# What is Cordova trying to tell me?

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova error message in logcat:

```
D/chromium(24894): Unknown chromium error: 0
D/CordovaLog(24894): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 2 : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
E/Web Console(24894): Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:2
```

I did not find an android_asset folder. My best bet is `myapp-debug.apk/assets/www/index.html`, but where should there be an issue in line 2?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="resources/icons/myApp-ico.png">
    <title>myApp</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
         /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #1985D0
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -15px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > * {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            width: 30px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
            0% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
            50% {
                opacity: 0
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * Sencha Blink - Testing
 * @author Jacky Nguyen <jacky@sencha.com>
 */
(function(global) {
    var head = global.document.head,
        Ext = global.Ext;

    if (typeof Ext == 'undefined') {
        global.Ext = Ext = {};
    }

    function write(content) {
        document.write(content);
    }

    function addMeta(name, content) {
        var meta = document.createElement('meta');

        meta.setAttribute('name', name);
        meta.setAttribute('content', content);
        head.appendChild(meta);
    }

    Ext.blink = function(options) {
        var scripts = options.js || [],
            styleSheets = options.css || [],
            i, ln, path, platform, theme;

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(
                    "@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {" +
                        "@-ms-viewport {width: 320px !important;}" +
                    "}" +
                    "@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {" +
                        "@-ms-viewport {width: 560px !important;}" +
                    "}"
                )
            );
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
        addMeta('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
        addMeta('apple-mobile-web-app-capable', 'yes');
        addMeta('apple-touch-fullscreen', 'yes');

        Ext.microloaded = true;

        var filterPlatform = window.Ext.filterPlatform = function(platform) {
            var profileMatch = false,
                ua = navigator.userAgent,
                j, jln, exclude;

            platform = [].concat(platform);

            function isPhone(ua) {
                var isMobile = /Mobile(\/|\s)/.test(ua);

                // Either:
                // - iOS but not iPad
                // - Android 2
                // - Android with "Mobile" in the UA

                return /(iPhone|iPod)/.test(ua) ||
                          (!/(Silk)/.test(ua) && (/(Android)/.test(ua) && (/(Android 2)/.test(ua) || isMobile))) ||
                          (/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(ua) && isMobile) ||
                          /(Windows Phone)/.test(ua);
            }

            function isTablet(ua) {
                return !isPhone(ua) && (/iPad/.test(ua) || /Android|Silk/.test(ua) || /(RIM Tablet OS)/.test(ua) ||
                    (/MSIE 10/.test(ua) && /; Touch/.test(ua)));
            }

            // Check if the ?platform parameter is set in the URL
            var paramsString = window.location.search.substr(1),
                paramsArray = paramsString.split("&"),
                params = {},
                testPlatform, i;

            for (i = 0; i < paramsArray.length; i++) {
                var tmpArray = paramsArray[i].split("=");
                params[tmpArray[0]] = tmpArray[1];
            }

            testPlatform = params.platform;
            if (testPlatform) {
                return platform.indexOf(testPlatform) != -1;
            }

            for (j = 0, jln = platform.length; j < jln; j++) {
                switch (platform[j]) {
                    case 'phone':
                        profileMatch = isPhone(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'tablet':
                        profileMatch = isTablet(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'desktop':
                        profileMatch = !isPhone(ua) && !isTablet(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'ios':
                        profileMatch = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'android':
                        profileMatch = /(Android|Silk)/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'blackberry':
                        profileMatch = /(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'safari':
                        profileMatch = /Safari/.test(ua) && !(/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(ua));
                        break;
                    case 'chrome':
                        profileMatch = /Chrome/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'ie10':
                        profileMatch = /MSIE 10/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'windows':
                        profileMatch = /MSIE 10/.test(ua) || /Trident/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'tizen':
                        profileMatch = /Tizen/.test(ua);
                        break;
                    case 'firefox':
                        profileMatch = /Firefox/.test(ua);
                }
                if (profileMatch) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };

        for (i = 0,ln = styleSheets.length; i < ln; i++) {
            path = styleSheets[i];

            if (typeof path != 'string') {
                platform = path.platform;
                exclude = path.exclude;
                theme = path.theme;
                path = path.path;
            }

            if (platform) {
                if (!filterPlatform(platform) || filterPlatform(exclude)) {
                    continue;
                }
                Ext.theme = {
                    name: theme || 'Default'
                };
            }
            write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+path+'">');
        }

        for (i = 0,ln = scripts.length; i < ln; i++) {
            path = scripts[i];

            if (typeof path != 'string') {
                platform = path.platform;
                exclude = path.exclude;
                path = path.path;
            }

            if (platform) {
                if (!filterPlatform(platform) || filterPlatform(exclude)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            write('<script src="'+path+'"></'+'script>');
        }
    }

})(this);

if(document.URL.indexOf('file://')==0) {
    oldBlink = Ext.blink;
    Ext.blink = function(options) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            oldBlink(options);
        }, false);
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could it be that "Line 2" does refer to something different entirely? If yes, what does it refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error to be caused by a script that is added to index.html by code from another javascript, using `Ext.Loader.injectScriptElement`, which roughly translates to the following JS:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

For some reason yet to be determined, the "object is not a function" error inside the referenced script is thrown inside Cordova WebView, but not inside Chrome. Once I found the line where it is thrown and corrected it, no more error is thrown.

For some other reason yet to be determined, it is thrown as an "error in index.html:2", whereas the error could also have read "error in locale-de.js:72".

Don't ask how I found it, this tiny little problem just required a whole week of debugging...

Answer (score 0):

[Prettify](http://www.jspretty.com/) this ugly line of code and try again to get a useful error message.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(e) {
        var c = e.document.head,
            b = e.Ext;
        if (typeof b == "undefined") {
            e.Ext = b = {}
        }

        function d(f) {
            document.write(f)
        }

        function a(f, g) {
            var h = document.createElement("meta");
            h.setAttribute("name", f);
            h.setAttribute("content", g);
            c.appendChild(h)
        }
        b.blink = function(p) {
            var j = p.js || [],
                n = p.css || [],
                l, m, o, g, k;
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
                var h = document.createElement("style");
                h.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {@-ms-viewport {width: 320px !important;}}@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {@-ms-viewport {width: 560px !important;}}"));
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(h)
            }
            a("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
            a("apple-mobile-web-app-capable", "yes");
            a("apple-touch-fullscreen", "yes");
            b.microloaded = true;
            var f = window.Ext.filterPlatform = function(u) {
                var D = false,
                    r = navigator.userAgent,
                    w, A, s;
                u = [].concat(u);

                function z(E) {
                    var i = /Mobile(\/|\s)/.test(E);
                    return /(iPhone|iPod)/.test(E) || (!/(Silk)/.test(E) && (/(Android)/.test(E) && (/(Android 2)/.test(E) || i))) || (/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(E) && i) || /(Windows Phone)/.test(E)
                }

                function y(i) {
                    return !z(i) && (/iPad/.test(i) || /Android|Silk/.test(i) || /(RIM Tablet OS)/.test(i) || (/MSIE 10/.test(i) && /; Touch/.test(i)))
                }
                var q = window.location.search.substr(1),
                    t = q.split("&"),
                    v = {},
                    B, x;
                for (x = 0; x < t.length; x++) {
                    var C = t[x].split("=");
                    v[C[0]] = C[1]
                }
                B = v.platform;
                if (B) {
                    return u.indexOf(B) != -1
                }
                for (w = 0, A = u.length; w < A; w++) {
                    switch (u[w]) {
                        case "phone":
                            D = z(r);
                            break;
                        case "tablet":
                            D = y(r);
                            break;
                        case "desktop":
                            D = !z(r) && !y(r);
                            break;
                        case "ios":
                            D = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "android":
                            D = /(Android|Silk)/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "blackberry":
                            D = /(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "safari":
                            D = /Safari/.test(r) && !(/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(r));
                            break;
                        case "chrome":
                            D = /Chrome/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "ie10":
                            D = /MSIE 10/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "windows":
                            D = /MSIE 10/.test(r) || /Trident/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "tizen":
                            D = /Tizen/.test(r);
                            break;
                        case "firefox":
                            D = /Firefox/.test(r)
                    }
                    if (D) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            };
            for (l = 0, m = n.length; l < m; l++) {
                o = n[l];
                if (typeof o != "string") {
                    g = o.platform;
                    exclude = o.exclude;
                    k = o.theme;
                    o = o.path
                }
                if (g) {
                    if (!f(g) || f(exclude)) {
                        continue
                    }
                    b.theme = {
                        name: k || "Default"
                    }
                }
                d('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + o + '">')
            }
            for (l = 0, m = j.length; l < m; l++) {
                o = j[l];
                if (typeof o != "string") {
                    g = o.platform;
                    exclude = o.exclude;
                    o = o.path
                }
                if (g) {
                    if (!f(g) || f(exclude)) {
                        continue
                    }
                }
                d('<script src="' + o + '"><\/script>')
            }
        }
    })(this);
    if (document.URL.indexOf("file://") == 0) {
        oldBlink = Ext.blink;
        Ext.blink = function(a) {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                oldBlink(a)
            }, false)
        }
    }
    Ext.blink({
        id: "8b19cfab-9dd1-44d0-892e-28f50a42aecd",
        js: [{
            path: "lzstring.js",
            update: "full",
            version: "1.0.0"
        }, {
            path: "microloader-enhancement.js",
            update: "full",
            version: "1.0.0"
        }, {
            path: "app.js",
            update: "full",
            version: "1.1.11"
        }],
        css: [{
            path: "resources/css/app.css",
            update: "full",
            theme: "Default"
        }, {
            path: "resources/css/sch.css",
            update: "full"
        }, {
            path: "resources/css/myApp.css",
            update: "full"
        }]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OK, I did, the new error message is `E/Web Console(25912): Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:2`...

Comment: Not really helpful, either. :-/
Cordova places the _index.html_ of an Android project in this folder: `android/bin/www`
Please check if your _index.html_ is there, too.

Comment: I checked the index.html that's inside the APK, and it contains the unminified code.

Comment: Sorry, without access to the whole project, it's hard to tell. Maybe someone else has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The webviewis just trying to make you understand that you're trying to call functions from the object Ext (like Ext.blink) but did not include any js library that would include that object.

You need to copy extjs somewhere in jour www folder and then add the missing `<script type="text/javascript" src="somewhere/extjs.js"></script>` line.

Next time, put your js in a separate file, you should get more accurate error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. First, I would like to point out that it isn't "my" JS, it is the Sencha Touch microloader, and it was the Sencha team that decided that the microloader should be put into index.html in a version compiled with Sencha Cmd. But, based on your assessment that Sencha Touch was not correctly loaded, I digged further. I found that the microloader correctly loads app.js, which contains Sencha Touch. `console.log` messages I left in app.js are sent to `logcat`: `D/CordovaLog(25912): file:///android_asset/www/app.js: Line 95312 : Synchronization store launched successfully`.

Comment: Well it seems I answered way too fast and those sencha guys have a very complicated way of doing ;) Ok, the Ext object seems to be supposed to be created at the begining of the code. But anyway you can try to put all the script in an external file to see if you get an actual line number. ps: is it normal that in the index.html in your question, the script tag is never ended?

Comment: I put the microloader into a separate js file. The error now is `D/CordovaLog(12051): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 2 : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.